# Can non-"Lead Free" fixtures be downstream of potable water?

Tags: plumbing, water, plumbing-fixture, irrigation, lead

I have an "outdoor" water line that splits from the main line. This line feeds an outdoor sink that is technically drinking water but not used very often. It also feeds an outdoor shower. Further down the line it connects to irrigation valves. There is a non-Lead Free vacuum breaker (Zurn 710) and then the valves.

I understand that the vacuum breaker makes it so water isn't sucked up from the hose and into the water supply, but is water that was in the body of the vacuum breaker then lead-contaminated and could it pass in the water to my sink?

[image]

Comment: Being non lead free and having lead can be two different things.   One is there is a very tiny amount of measurable lead, so can't be lead free.  The other is enough lead to harm you.  Doubt very much anything made to be connected to drinking water will contain lead in amounts deem dangerous, a very few parts per million.

Comment: Adding lead to the brass makes it cheaper; a new hospital in Australia had to be replumbed due to noticeable lead levels because of these fittings.

Answer (score -1):

Fittings for potable water can have some lead the percentage is low but not zero to tell the truth, the use of lead free solder , indium or other metals like silver are more expensive than lead but don’t have the negative side affects of lead.
According to some government sources there is no amount of lead that is safe.
Let’s say this again; there is no amount of lead that is safe.
Now look at potable water standards and a trace amount is ok in the parts.

My grand parents always ran the water for a bit 30 seconds at least and even washed the ice cubes as ice freezes the impurities on the outside first so the old school practice of running water and ringing ice cubes still has truth in science today.

If there is lead any place in the system it can backstream, but a 1/2 minute or more may take everything out and make the water safe to drink but what do I know, I still drink water out of a hose, been doing this for 60+ years from family photos